# Pandas. Convert table structure

Tags: python, pandas

How can I convert this table:

| iso | pref_name | pref_score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AFG | pref_01 | 1 |
| AFG | pref_02 | 2 |
| AFG | pref_03 | 3 |
| ZMB | pref_01 | 3 |
| ZMB | pref_02 | 2 |
| ZMB | pref_03 | 1 |
| ARM | NaN | NaN |
| ARM | NaN | NaN |
| ARM | NaN | NaN |

to this table:

| iso | pref_01 | pref_02 | pref_03 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AFG | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| ZMB | 3 | 2 | 1 |
| ARM | NaN | NaN | NaN |

and vice-versa

I've tried to pivot it ([How can I pivot a dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-can-i-pivot-a-dataframe)) but it wasn't sucessful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answers.

Basically to convert first table to second one I used `.pivot`:

```
df2 = df1.pivot(index='iso3',columns='pref_name', values='pref_score').sort_values('iso3')
```

To convert second table to the first one I used `.melt`:

```
df1 = df2.melt(id_vars=['iso'], var_name='pref_name', value_name='pref_score')
```

It worked just fine

Answer (score 1):

You cannot [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) directly as there is no information to pivot the **ARM** values of **iso** (all **pref_name** are NaN).

You can `pivot` without it (using [`dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html)) and [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with the [`unique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html) values of **iso** afterwards:

```
(df.dropna()
   .pivot(index='iso', columns='pref_name', values='pref_score')
   .reindex(df['iso'].unique())
)
```

output:

```
pref_name  pref_01  pref_02  pref_03
iso                                 
AFG            1.0      2.0      3.0
ZMB            3.0      2.0      1.0
ARM            NaN      NaN      NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

**I think this is a bug with pandas**. I'm using version:

```
In [334]: pd.__version__
Out[334]: '1.2.3'
```

As per [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) docs:

> dropna bool, default True.
> Do not include columns whose entries are all NaN.

So ideally using `dropna=False` should solve your issue. But it doesn't.

```
In [333]: pd.pivot_table(df, 'pref_score', 'iso', 'pref_name', dropna=False)
Out[333]: 
pref_name  pref_01  pref_02  pref_03
iso                                 
AFG            1.0      2.0      3.0
ZMB            3.0      2.0      1.0
```

It's better to **open a bug** with pandas.

Comment: @Umar.H Please read properly. I said, `dropna=False` should include the `NaN` entries, but it doesn't. That's the bug.

Comment: my fault sorry!

Answer (score 1):

As a work around, you can convert your iso column to a categorical dtype first and then run `pivot_table`. By using a categorical dtype with the default argument of `pd.pivot_table(..., observed=False)` you can essentially force all values of your groupers ("iso" and/or "pref_name" in this case) to be present in the output.

```
df.astype({"iso": "category"}).pivot_table('pref_score', 'iso', 'pref_name', dropna=False)

pref_name  pref_01  pref_02  pref_03
iso
AFG            1.0      2.0      3.0
ARM            NaN      NaN      NaN
ZMB            3.0      2.0      1.0
```